# Cannot install texlive-full, kpsewhich frozen on 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, latex

I'm trying to install `texlive-full` on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with this command:

```
apt install texlive-full
```

All required packages are downloaded. When it starts to setup the packages, it starts the `kpsewhich` program in the background and waits for it to finish. But it never exits and it uses 100% CPU. I left my computer turned on for a whole night and it was still running in the morning. If I kill the `kpsewhich` process, then it gets started again. If I kill it about 3 more times then `apt` shows this:

```
Terminated
Terminated
Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/bin/tl-paper line 112.
Terminated
Terminated
Can't use string ("2") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/bin/tl-paper line 112.
dpkg: error processing package texlive-base (--configure):
```

If I retry the same `apt` command, then it does exactly the same again. The full command line that takes forever is this:

```
kpsewhich --progname=pdftex --format=tex pdftexconfig.tex
```

How can I install `texlive`?

**UPDATE**

Output of `apt-cache policy texlive-full texlive-binaries`:

```
texlive-full:
  Telepítve: 2017.20180305-1
  Jelölt:    2017.20180305-1
  Verziótáblázat:
 *** 2017.20180305-1 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
texlive-binaries:
  Telepítve: 2017.20170613.44572-8ubuntu0.1
  Jelölt:    2017.20170613.44572-8ubuntu0.1
  Verziótáblázat:
 *** 2017.20170613.44572-8ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2017.20170613.44572-8build1 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `kpsewhich --version`:

```
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Karl Berry & Olaf Weber.
License LGPLv2.1+: GNU Lesser GPL version 2.1 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Output of `which kpsewhich`:

```
/usr/bin/kpsewhich
```

**UPDATE 2**

Rebooted my computer, and tried to update all packages and install again. Now it succeeded. I'm not sure what happened. I guess I'll never find out.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy texlive-full texlive-binaries`, `kpsewhich --version` and `which kpsewhich` to the question.

Comment: I'll do that but that computer is at my workplace, I can only do it on monday.

Comment: Request outputs added. Sorry for the hungarian words, they were printed this way. I could update the locale of this machine to english but the locale is important and it might be a factor in the installation failure.